# create pandas df from dictionary but in a special format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Supposed I have the dictionary d:

```
d = dict(A =[1,2], B=[1,2,3,4])
print d
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

I would like to create a pandas `df` with two cols labeled `nodeid` and `rowid` that looks like this:

```
nodeid  rowid
A       1 
A       2 
B       1 
B       2 
B       3 
B       4
```

All the examples I have found that create a pandas df from a dict give the dict key as the name of the col and then row entries are whether that key had a particular value, with a `NaN` if that node didn't have that value.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, v) for (k, l) in d.items() for v in l], 
              columns=['nodeid', 'rowid'])
```

and it gives:

```
    nodeid  rowid
0   A   1
1   A   2
2   B   1
3   B   2
4   B   3
5   B   4
```

Comment: Note that In terms of computational performance mine should be faster for a large number of keys and values.

Comment: your solution was bascially instantaneous

Comment: clean and clever.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[k,d[k][i]] for k in d for i in range(len(d[k]))], columns= ['nodeid', 'rowid'])
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
  nodeid  rowid
0      A      1
1      A      2
2      B      1
3      B      2
4      B      3
5      B      4
```

Comment: I have 3000 keys and values vary for each key

Comment: It should not be a problem.

Comment: @profhoff Just checked. The code should work with any number of keys in `d`.

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
pd.Series(d).apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).\
    rename(columns={'level_0':'nodeid',0:'rowid'})
  nodeid  rowid
0      A    1.0
1      A    2.0
0      B    1.0
1      B    2.0
2      B    3.0
3      B    4.0
```